# Formatting Date in Razor page

Tags: blazor

Here's an example of my code.

```
<p>Last Performed: @piece.LastPerformed</p>
<p>Last Performed: @(piece.LastPerformed is null ? "unknown" : @piece.LastPerformed.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"))</p>
```

The first line produces "Last Performed: 9/12/2022 9:19:20 PM".

The second line is what I'm trying to do to format the date, but if it's left as is an not commented out, produces an error, so typically I have it commented out until I can get the code right.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

A better option is to use the [null-conditional](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#null-conditional-operators--and-) and [null-coalescing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator) operators:

```
<p>Last Performed: @(piece.LastPerformed?.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") ?? "unknown")</p>
```

A `DateTime?` is shorthand for `Nullable<DateTime>`. The null conditional operator can be used to call members of the actual type if it's not null, otherwise null is returned. This is equivalent to :

```
piece.LastPerformed == null) ? null : piece.LastPerformed.Value.ToString(...);
```

The null coalescing operator returns the first non-null argument. It's equivalent to :

```
(arg ==null)?replacement:arg
```

Answer (score 1):

`LastPerformed` is nullable so you need to use the [`Value`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.nullable-1.value?view=net-6.0) property to get the `DateTime` value:

```
<p>Last Performed: @(piece.LastPerformed is null ? "unknown" : @piece.LastPerformed.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"))</p>
```

[Documentation for C# Nullable value types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/nullable-value-types)

Comment: Seriously? Just add .Value?  Ugh, thank you!